# Getting Error while running WOWZA streaming server and WEBRTC [ via firefox ]

Tags: websocket, streaming, webrtc, wowza

I'm using latest wowza streaming engine and while trying to send stream via webrtc, I get the following error.

I've followed the instructions on the official wowza docs and double checked them.

```
wsConnection.onerror: {"isTrusted":true} webrtc.js:260:1
stopPublisher webrtc.js:314:2
wsConnection.onclose webrtc.js:255:3
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://172.16.14.237:1935/webrtc-session.json.
```

Please let me know how to resolve this or what's causing this so I can move ahead with my project.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you have set up an SSL Host Port in your VHost file. You need to follow the steps shown in this part of the article
https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-use-webrtc-with-wowza-streaming-engine#install

It also appears that your StreamLock certificate is invalid
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=`https://<YOUR-STREAMLOCK-ID>.streamlock.net`

So please ensure that you download the the following keystore file (.jks) from your Wowza Portal: `<YOUR-STREAMLOCK-ID>.streamlock.net`

Place that keystore file in your Wowza /conf directory

Create an HTTPS/StreamLock Host Port for port 443 using this keystore,
https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-get-ssl-certificates-from-the-streamlock-service#config4-0

Confirm that the Host Port is responding on port 443 by entering the following in a browser (it should return the Wowza version number)

```
https://<YOUR-STREAMLOCK-ID>.streamlock.net
```

and when publishing as WebRTC use the proper wss URL (don't specify port 1935). For example if using our example publisher
https://www.wowza.com/_private/webrtc/4.7.4/publish/

then the SDP URL would be `wss://<YOUR-STREAMLOCK-ID>.streamlock.net/webrtc-session.json`